# frequency axis in continuous wavelet transform plot (scaleogram) in python

Tags: python, signal-processing, wavelet, pywt

I have an EEG signal that I'm interested in analyzing it in both time and frequency domains. I have already used scipy.signal.spectrogram function, but I think using wavelets can yield better results for feature extraction.
I tried running the continuous wavelet transform on artificial signal that I created as follows:

```
fs = 128.0
sampling_period = 1/fs
t = np.linspace(0, 2, 2*fs)
x = chirp(t,10,2,40,'quadratic')

coef, freqs = pywt.cwt(x, np.arange(1,50),'morl', 
sampling_period=sampling_period)
```

and then I plotted the coef matrix:

```
plt.matshow(coef)
plt.show()
```

[image: the resuls for the code above]

My question is how can I adjust the scale and time axes?

Answer (score 4):

The function `plt.matshow(coef)` does not use the time and and frequency arrays for creating axes (but it creates sample-index based axes).

I suggest using `plt.pcolormesh(t, freqs, coef)`, so the time and frequency are used for the axes. Then you can play with scale – say, put the frequency axis in log scale – and produce something like that:

[image]

Here is the code that produced the image, derived from your example:

```py
import pywt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.signal import chirp

# Define signal
fs = 128.0
sampling_period = 1 / fs
t = np.linspace(0, 2, 2 * fs)
x = chirp(t, 10, 2, 40, 'quadratic')

# Calculate continuous wavelet transform
coef, freqs = pywt.cwt(x, np.arange(1, 50), 'morl',
                       sampling_period=sampling_period)

# Show w.r.t. time and frequency
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 2))
plt.pcolor(t, freqs, coef)

# Set yscale, ylim and labels
plt.yscale('log')
plt.ylim([1, 100])
plt.ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.xlabel('Time (sec)')
plt.savefig('egg.png', dpi=150)
```